# python fsync() on network drive hangs

Tags: python, linux, mount, cifs, fsync

I write some data to a file using the following function:

```
def WriteTo1File(self, output_file, text):
    output_file.write(text)
    output_file.flush()
    os.fsync(output_file.fileno())
```

The `fsync()` call is mandatory to handle IOError: if I don't use it when a network drive is unreachable, the function `write()` works on its local buffer and raises no exceptions.

The problem is that after a few write operations, the function `fsync()` hangs. What is it related to?
The local machine is Linux running python 2.7. The drives are mounted with mount.cifs.
The remote disk is on a local server which is always reachable.
If I unmount the remote disk, `fsync()` returns after few tens of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the `nostrictsync` mount option.

There is some information regarding this at https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/Documentation-filesystems-cifs-README.

Comment: Thank you but I get the same result if I mount the disk this way:`sudo /usr/bin/mount.cifs //server_ip/disk_name /home/mika/todo/local_name/ -o cred=/home/mika/todo/.credentials,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,nostrictsync`